# Erratic behavior of System.Security.WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole() method

Tags: c#

Does System.Security.WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole() method validate the user membership recursively? 
I tried the following and got erratic results:

Case 1:
Create a security group - SGroup1
Add - NT Authority\Authenticated Users to SGroup1.
Log off and log on
Call IsInRole() for the logged in user. The API return true.

Case 2:
Create a security group - SGroup1
Add - Administrators to SGroup1.
Log off and log on as an Administrator.
Call IsInRole() for the logged in user. The API returns false.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What operating system are you running on? If you're running on Windows Vista or Windows 7 (or their Server 2008/R2 brethren), the following applies. As noted in the `Note` under Remarks in the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs485fwh.aspx) for `WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole` (my emphasis):

> In Windows Vista, User Account Control
>   (UAC) determines the privileges of a
>   user. If you are a member of the
>   Built-in Administrators group, you are
>   assigned two run-time access tokens: a
>   standard user access token and an
>   administrator access token. **By
>   default, you are in the standard user
>   role.** When you attempt to perform a
>   task that requires administrative
>   privileges, you can dynamically
>   elevate your role by using the Consent
>   dialog box. The code that executes the
>   IsInRole  method does not display the
>   Consent dialog box. **The code returns
>   false if you are in the standard user
>   role, even if you are in the Built-in
>   Administrators group.** You can elevate
>   your privileges before you execute the
>   code by right-clicking the application
>   icon and indicating that you want to
>   run as an administrator.

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2008 R2. Running the application as an administrator also does not solve the issue. Are there any windows logs where i can find the reason for the failure?

Comment: Just to confirm, by "running the application as Administrator" you do mean "right click the application, choosing 'Run as Administrator' from the context menu and saying yes to the UAC prompt', right? =)

Comment: Yes. I even tried logging in with Administrator credentials, still it doesnt work.

This is what I did -
- Create a group - SGroup1
- Open a cmd prompt and do - net localgroup "SGroup1" "Administrators" /add [ this adds BUILTIN\Administrators to SGroup1 ] 
- Login as a member under Administrators group and call IsInRole() for the logged on user